# Solution Loosed Source Control Binding everytime is is closed

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

Every time I open up my solution it loses its binding to source control (Using VSTS-TFS).  All the other projects remain bound.  I go to File|Source Control|Advanced|Change Source Control and re-bind it.   Everything is fine until I close the solution or shut down VS.   When I re-open the solution it is unbound again.  Happens every time.   Even when branching the source, the problem follows when opening the solution in the branches.

Question: Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Also, where is the source control binding information for the solution and project stored?

Answer (score 1):

You could open the `xx.csproj` files, there should be some elements in the `.csproj` files such as:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

There should be something similar in the solution file, open the solution with text.

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 1
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF2xxxxC}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = https://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
    SccProjectUniqueName0 = HelloWorld.csproj
    SccProjectName0 = .
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProvider0 = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF2xxxxC}
EndGlobalSection
```

You could compare files in the special solution with others(works well) in your TFS server, it there are something wrong, try to fix up both `.sln` and `.csproj`  files manually.

After this check in the changes, also try to [clear VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), finally check the issue fixed or not.